# Tracking work schedule and calculating work hours using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, microsoft-excel-2016

I have to make a schedule in a calendar format every month and I often make changes of where people go and when people work.

If there is a way, I would like to use a formula that will track each name and then take the hours worked in the next column and calculate the total hours for the week.

I am sorry if there is a similar Question asked but I could not find any that helped me.

Here's a screenshot of what I am working with:

[image: Schedule. Picture of what I am working with.]

Comment: Sounds like you are new to Excel? In a cell you can press the `=` sign and then a list comes up; this is formula. `=SUM` is one of these formulae, it means to add up. You can add cells: =SUM(A1:C2) or =SUM(A1, B1, C2). Do a little fiddling around with it and you will get the hang of it in no time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keith, 
There are few simple ways to do this by parsing the cell contents, but will need to change the format of the calendar since I see few cells that are merged. Are you able to change the format or does it have to be this way?

Comment: Hello ejbites, I am not what I would call proficient in Excel however, I am not a novice either, The =Sum I use on a lot of things including the report uploaded and that was not what I asked, but I do appreciate the response.

Comment: Hello @Vidhya S, I just saw your response and I had come to the same conclusion as you did. After staring at it for hours and trying different things I had to reformat the calendar and separate the merged cells. and use the =Sumif formula. It took a few hours of work to complete. However, It has made my life so much easier when I need to make quick changes or even making the schedule. The only thing I could not get the way I need it was making a cell to calculate the time worked into hours but only show in the cell like this "9-5". If you have any Ideas please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

After staring at it for hours and trying different things I had to reformat the calendar and separate the merged cells. and use the =Sumif formula. It took a few hours of work to complete. However, It has made my life so much easier when I need to make quick changes or even making the schedule. The only thing I could not get the way I need it was making a cell to calculate the time worked into hours but only show in the cell like this "9-5"[Upload of final product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBpVY.png)

Comment: Keith, great to know you found an easier way! So, if you want the hours to be calculated automatically, you would need the start time in one cell (say 0900) and end time in another (1700) and one more cell to calculate the difference (which will give you 8).  If you want it to look like "9 - 5", I would trick it by have 4 cells like this : 09   -   17   8 : and remove the borders in between. Does that make sense?